# Point and a normal vector question

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to calculate a normal vector given three points in the plane.  My results do not agree with what I expect, and I would appreciate guidance.  I'm using the following [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)) definition:

$n = (p_2 - p_1) \times (p_3 - p_1)$

Points:
$p_1 = (1, 1, 1), p_2 = (1, 0, 0), p_3 = (0, 1, 0)$

$p_2 - p_1 = (0, -1, -1)$

$p_3 - p_1 = (-1, 0, -1)$

It's my understanding that $p_2 - p_1$ and $p_3 - p_1$ represent two perpendicular vectors specifying the plane through the origin.  We then take the cross product to get the norm and the determinant can be used to calculate the cross product.

$\begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k \\
0 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{vmatrix}$

$i \begin{vmatrix}
   -1 & -1 \\
   0 & -1 \\
   \end{vmatrix}
 + j \begin{vmatrix}
   0 & -1 \\
   -1 & -1 \\
   \end{vmatrix}
 - k \begin{vmatrix}
   0 & -1 \\
   -1 & 0 \\
   \end{vmatrix}
$

$i(-1*-1 - 0) + j(-1*-1 - 0) - k(-1*-1 - 0)$

$i + j - k$

This vector does not appear normal to the plane when I look at a graph.  Does anyone know if I made an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know if I made an error?

It should be $i(-1\times-1 - 0) - j(0 - (-1\times-1)) + k(0 - (-1\times-1))= i \color{red}+ j - k$.

Comment: The coefficient of $k$ is also wrong -- another sign error.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnHughes; I edited to include that as well, though somehow OP got the sign of $k$ correct in the final answer

Comment: Correcting the sign error produces the correct norm vector.